# Alternate of df.fillna('', inplace=True)? For pandas 0.25.1

Tags: python, pandas, performance, data-visualization

I am trying to use df.fillna('', inplace=True) but my company's server has pandas 0.25.1 and giving an error. Is bfill going to help? I saw that it a synonym of fillna?

Comment: Edit: It gives the error AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'fillna'

Comment: You can actually [edit] your question instead of putting "Edit:" in the comments.

Comment: It looks like `df` is not a `DataFrame`…

Comment: What gives `type(df)`?

Comment: @mozway: I know what you are trying to say. But the code works on my laptop. But gives error on the server.

Comment: If we can't reproduce it, we likely can't help you